# Same absolute position in different screen size Android imageview

Tags: android, imageview, position, screen, absolute

How can i have same  imageview absolute-position in different screen size?

```
  <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:background="#000000">
        <ImageView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/road"
            android:src="@drawable/road" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/car"
            android:src="@drawable/car"
            android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="168dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The car position isn't same for different screen size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google library `PercentRelativeLayout` with this `library` you can set **width**, **height** and **margin** of your views by procentege which is great because in all screen they look the same and of course it is not hard to code it. Here example:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

you must add this line in your build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
}
```

**Official documentation by Google** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Hope this help for your case!